# How can I install Firefox version 40.0 in my Centos-6 system?

Tags: firefox

I have to do some testing stuff on older versions of firefox.My current mozilla version is 45.3. But i want mozilla 40 for testing purposes. How can I install that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get older version of firefox from here:

> https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/40.0/

Select your OS (linux here) and language then download tar file. Extract tarball and run firefox from that directory.

Comment: i am unable to download from this website.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/firefox/40.0+build4-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 . I found other link of this version, but it's for ubuntu. I'm not sure whether it'll be run fine one centOS.